# What is the golden rule for when to split code up into functions?

Tags: function, modularity, decoupling, fragmentation

It's good to split code up into functions and classes for modularity / decoupling, but if you do it too much, you get really fragmented code which is also not good.

**What is the golden rule for when to split code up into functions?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really does depend on the size and scope of your project.

I tend to split things into functions **every time there is something repeated**, and that repetition generalized/abstracted, following the golden rule of [**DRY**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) (**Do not repeat yourself**).

As far as splitting up classes, I tend to follow the Object Oriented Programming mantra of isolating what is the same from what is different, and split up classes if one class is implementing more an one large theoretical "idea" or entity.

But honestly if your code is too fragmented and opaque, you should try considering refactoring into a different approach/paradigm.

Comment: +1: Second concept is the SRP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle

Answer (score 6):

If I can give it a good name (better than the code it replaces), it becomes a function

Comment: This is really a "golden" rule :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you generally have to think of a chunk of codes have a chance of being reuse. It comes with experience to figure that out and plan ahead.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the answers that concentrate on reusability and eliminating repetition, but I also believe that readability is at least as important. So in addition to repetition, I would look for pieces of code (classes, functions, blocks, etc.) that do more than one thing.

If the name associated with the code does not describe what it does, then that is a good time to refactor that code into units which each have a [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and a descriptive name. This [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) will help both reusability, and readability.

Useful code can stick around for a long time, so it is important that you (or ideally someone else) can go back and easily understand code that was written months or years before.

Answer (score 1):

Probably my own personal rule is if it is more than 2 lines long, and is referenced more than once on the same page (ASP.net), or a few times spread over a couple of pages, than I will write a function to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught that anything you do more than once should be a function.  Anything similar should have a parent class, and above all else consult your source code "standards" within your organization.  The latter mostly deals with formatting.

Comment: I'd be careful with advocating inheritance just to provide easy access to common functions. Composition is better. Leave inheritance to expressing `is-a` relationships.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, write the feature you're adding. (Notice the word "First", we tend to write a function/class **before** writing the feature, which might lead to having too many fragmentation).

**Then**, **review** the code you just wrote/changed, **find** what blocks of the code that is:

- 3-lines or more, **and**..
- **repeated**, **and**..
- Can be **grouped** under a **named** function. Because code is written by us, people (not programs), to be read/changed later by us, people (not programs).